# Google Closure Compiler incomplete alias created for namespace

Tags: javascript, namespaces, google-closure-compiler

I'm having an issue with Closure Compiler. This is my function :

```
Editor.Elements.Map = function(type, view, x, y) {
    var element = type[0].toUpperCase() + type.slice(1);
    if(typeof Editor.Elements[element] === 'function') {
        return new Editor.Elements[element](view).create(x, y);
    }
    return null;
}
```

Which would call a class like this :

```
/**
 *  @constructor
 *  @extends {Editor.Elements.Element}
 *  @param view (object) {Editor.View}
 */
Editor.Elements.Circle = function(view) {

    Editor.Elements.Element.apply(this, arguments);

    if (!(view instanceof Editor.View)) {
        throw new Error('An Instance of Editor.View is required.');
    }

    var me = this, _me = {};

    ...
}
```

I'm getting the following warning :

```
JSC_UNSAFE_NAMESPACE: incomplete alias created for namespace Editor.Elements
```

Which refers to these two lines :

```
if(typeof Editor.Elements[element] === 'function') { /* ... */ } // 1.
return new Editor.Elements[element](view).create(x, y);          // 2.
```

Even if I was to remove the first warning I can't get ride of the second. Is there any way I can work around this possibly with annotations ?

Comment: How are you calling `gcc` (any arguments/options)? I recently learned that using `--language_in=ECMASCRIPT5` opens up the use of a lot of reserved keywords.

Comment: I'm only using `--compilation_level ADVANCED_OPTIMIZATIONS` I'll give `--language_in=ECMASCRIPT5` a go.

Answer (score 5):

The warning comes from the Collapse Properties optimization pass. The compiler is warning you that the following transformation might occur:

```
Editor$Elements$Circle = function(view) { ... }
```

In this case, accessing `Editor.Elements['Circle']` will fail because `Circle` is no longer a property of `Editor$Elements`.

This also causes problems with consistent property access:

```
var element = type[0].toUpperCase() + type.slice(1);
if(typeof Editor.Elements[element] === 'function') {
```

This case is equivalent to `Editor.Elements['Circle']` which is accessing a property by the quoted name and the original form is dotted. The compiler can rename the dotted access and will leave the quoted access alone thus breaking your code.

Comment: See ADVANCED mode in this document:  https://developers.google.com/closure/compiler/docs/limitations and "Implications of object property flattening" specifically.